# Как скрыть/показать форму для расчетов

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Есть 2 больших вычисления на картинках[!начало большого вычисления](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7LmR.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7LmR.png)
[[image: продолжение большого вычисления]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7LmR.png)[[image: введите сюда описание изображения]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX15C.png)

Я хотел бы чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Потери напора на преодоление сопротивлений при движении воды в" открывался бы список для выбора вычисления "a)  Заливочных трубах" и "b)    Затрубном пространстве", А при нажатии на выбранный список соответствующая ему форма. Как реализовать это.

Comment: какое отношение имеют приведенные Вами *скрины* к указанным Вами меткам?

Comment: Вы спутали. Это не ресурс с вашими слугами

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если нужно просто показать/скрыть форму с расчетами то можна сделать так:

```js
$(".cal-a").click(function() {
  $('.calculation-a').toggle();
});

$(".cal-b").click(function() {
  $('.calculation-b').toggle();
});
```

```css
.cal-a,
.cal-b {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: blue;
}
.calculation-a,
.calculation-b {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="math">
  <div class="title">Потери напора на преодоление сопротивлений при движении воды в</div>
  <div class="cal-a">a) Заливочных трубах</div>
  <div class="calculation-a">
    <p>Форма с расчетами a</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cal-b">b) Затрубном пространстве</div>
  <div class="calculation-b">
    <p>Форма с расчетами b</p>
  </div>
</div>
```